# Redux persist rehydrate previous auth state too late

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have setup routes that are meant to be authenticated to redirect user to login page if unauthenticated. I have also setup `redux-persist` to auto dehydrate my auth state so user remains login on refresh. The problem is this rehydration is too late and user is already redirected to login page

[image]

The 1st location change is to an authenticated route, the 2nd is to login. Notice rehydrate comes after these. Ideally it should be right after @@INIT at least?

Comment: You can solve it by two different approaches, 1. Create a page processing/loading and when you receive user authentication status redirect to page you need. 2. The 1st location should be login and if already logged then redirect. Better ux

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `persistStore` function which is used to make your store persistent have a third param `callback` which is invoked after store rehydration is done. You have to start your app with some sort of preloader, which waits for rehydration to happen and renders your full application only after it finishes.

`redux-persist` docs even [have a recipe](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/558a3190f11f1a8a8024dc51ab6941382dfeed1d/docs/recipes.md#delay-render-until-rehydration-complete) for this scenario. In your case all the `react-router` stuff should be rendered inside initial loader as well:

```
export default class Preloader extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { rehydrated: false }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    persistStore(this.props.store, {}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true });
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.rehydrated){
      return <Loader />;
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const store = ...; // creating the store but not calling persistStore yet
ReactDOM.render(<Preloader store={store} />, ... );
```

Comment: There is also the `PersistGate` component now that makes delaying rendering until rehydrated even easier and more logical: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: @SomethingOn doesn't help it seems. Have the same issue with PersistGate even.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou sounds like you may need to add some checks in to determine when/what to render. The PersistGate shouldn't render any child components until the store has been rehydrated. Set a breakpoint in the render method and verify that it's not being called until the rehydrate action has fired. If it's rendering after the store has been rehydrated, verify your containers/selectors, etc are setting the props appropriately for your component.

Answer (score 0):

When user refresh the page, The first `LOCATION_CHANGE` will fire because you sync history with store. However, it only syncs the history and does not redirect user to anywhere yet.

The only thing matters is the second `LOCATION_CHANGE`, which should occur after `persistStore()`. Good news is `persistStore()` has a call back.

```
const store = ...

// persist store
persistStore(store, options, () => {
  const states = store.getState();

  // if authenticated, do nothing,
  // if not, redirect to login page
  if (!states.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    // redirect to login page
  }
});

render(...);
```

Hope this can help to solve your problem.